# access my website url using a password on the URL

Tags: security

lets say for example i have my website like that:

http://whatever.herokuapp.com/
and i don't want anyone to view it until he enter a password on the URL like that.
http://whatever.herokuapp.com/pw=1231fd1ffs

i am using angular for this project and i am connecting to some apis.
how i can do something like this.
this is what i am looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do a GET request and give it the parameter as:

```
http://whatever.herokuapp.com/?pw=1231fd1ffs
```

Then, on server side you should check if the password is, in fact, correct and if it is just return the new web.

However, this is not really advisable. Anyone could access if they have the full link with the password. Instead of this you should do a form with a POST request asking for the password. Or even better, a users db so everyone would have his own password and third persons will not be allowed to log in.

After POST request just return the full web the same way you would do it with a GET